# How can I build WidgetGallery in Wt examples?

Tags: c++, frameworks, wt

I installed Wt 3.3.3 from source on Ubuntu and compiled all the examples.  Now I'm trying to run WidgetGallery example by following instructions in README.md file, but the required ***widgetgallery.wt*** file is missing, in fact, the whole ***../../build/examples/widgetgallery*** directory is missing.

This is how I try to run it:

```
../../build/examples/widgetgallery/widgetgallery.wt --docroot docroot --approot approot --http-address 0.0.0.0 --http-port 8080
```

How do I build ***widgetgallery.wt***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

widget gallery requires a C++11 capable compiler and you must explicitly enable C++11 support in Wt for gcc by specifying the appropriate C++11 flag:

```
cmake .... -DWT_CPP_11_MODE=-std=c++11
```

the boost libraries should in fact also be compiled with the same flag, since it's API and class layout changes for some classes when C++11 is turned on

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm.  From "build" directory on Ubuntu I did **cmake .. -DWT_CPP_11_MODE=-std=c++11** and then **make** and **make -C examples**.  On Raspbian (Raspberry Pi) I had to first upgrade to gcc 4.8 because it would not compile under gcc 4.6. I used jessie repositories to upgrade gcc.

Comment: To compile boost on Ubuntu **./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=clang** then **./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-std=c++11"** and then **./b2 install**.  Also may need **apt-get install clang** first.